# Concatenar en c

Tags: c

esperando que te encuentres bien en esta cuarentena, vengo a preguntar al foro por primera vez.

Mi tarea es larga y dentro de una de las cosas debo hacer una función que reciba como parametro un char y que haga el encrypt de acuerdo al cuadrado de polibio.

Mi gran duda es como puedo crear una sola variable que tenga todos los numeros para asi poder retornarla, ya que el codigo como tal imprime de la siguiente manera:

> Fernando
>
> F = un entero
>
> e = a otro entero
>
> y asi...

Entonces como lo hago para guardar todos esos enteros en una sola variable que pueda retornar

```
    int i,j,poly[MAXCHAR],x,k;
    i=0;
    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        if((str[i]>=0&&str[i]<=31)||(str[i]>=33&&str[i]<65)||(str[i]>90&&str[i]<97)||(str[i]>122&&str[i]<=127))
        {
            NULL;
        }
        i++;
    }
    x=0;
    k=11;
    //Assigning Polybius Square numbers to alphabets
    for(i=0;i<=25;i++)
    {
        if(i<=8)
        {
            if(i%5==0&&i!=0)
            {
                k+=5;
                poly[x]=k++;
            }
            else{
                poly[x]=k++;
            }
        }
        if(i>=10)
        {
            if(i%5==0&&i!=0)
            {
                poly[x]=k++;
                k+=5;
            }
            else{
                poly[x]=k++;
            }
        }
        if(i==9)
        {
            poly[x]=24;
        }
        x++;
    }
    i=0;
//    printf("Encrypted Code using Polybius Square Cipher \n");
    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(!((str[i]>=0&&str[i]<=31)||(str[i]>=33&&str[i]<65)||(str[i]>90&&str[i]<97)||(str[i]>122&&str[i]<=127)))
        {
            if(str[i]>='A'&&str[i]<='Z')
            {
                printf("%d",poly[str[i]-'A']);
            }
            if(str[i]>='a'&&str[i]<='z')
            {
                printf("%d",poly[str[i]-'a']);
            }
        }
        if(str[i]==' ')
        {
            printf("%c",str[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
 ``
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. La función para concatenar strings es *strcat*, pero no me queda claro como se aplicaría a tu código, no tengo claro lo que pretendes hacer.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según entiendo lo que quieres hacer es guardar el resultado en una variable y retornar, te recomiendo esto:

lo que puedes hacer es esto como sabes que el cifrado polibio va de 2 en 2 (digitos) se puede hacer esto:

"BIEN" La salida seria : 12 24 15 33

```
-> Entra 12, 0*100, 0+12, 12
-> Entra 24, 12*100, 1200+24, 1224
-> Entra 15, 1224*100, 122400+15, 122415
-> Entra 33, 122414*100, 12241500+33, 12241533
```

En codigo seria:

```
int concat(int num){
    static int aux = 0;
    aux = (aux * 100) + num;
    return aux;
}


int main(){
    int num;
    num = concat(12);
    printf("EL numero es: %d\n",num); #imprime 12
    num = concat(24);
    printf("EL numero es: %d\n",num); #imprime 1224
    return 1;
}
```

Tal vez sepas o no pero lo que hace **static** es guardar el valor de la variable **en la función** entonces al llamar la función estará guardado el valor, ojo no es una variable global, si llamas aux desde el main o de otra función dará error.

Comment: te amo, sos un pro <3

Answer (score 0):

De manera simple, si quieres guardar varios valores del mismo tipo en una sola variable, esa variable debe ser algún tipo de vector, matriz o colección, que tenga operaciones que permitan añadir elementos al contenedor.

De manera rudimentaria, y como se ha comentado antes, puedes guardar los enteros en una sola variable entera aplicando un peso cada vez, que si tus números son siempre de 1 o 2 dígitos, puedes aplicar un peso de 100. Así podrías guardar los números `a` y `b` como `a * 100 + b`.

```
int a = 13;
int b = 1;
int resultado = a * 100 + b;    // resultado = 1301
```

Otra forma de hacerlo es utilizando vectores de números enteros.

```
int a = 13;
int b = 1;
int resultado[NUMEROS];    // NUMEROS = 2
resultado[0] = a;
resultado[1] = b;
```

Por supuesto aquí tienes que declarar un vector de tamaño fijo, por lo que si tienes muchos datos, o los vas leyendo por teclado y su número total puede variar, te tocará implementar un vector con redimensión dinámica, y eso es bastante complicado, porque hay que manejar memoria dinámica manualmente, reservando y liberando memoria RAM mediante las funciones `malloc`, `realloc` y `free`, y utilizando punteros.

```
int a = 13;
int b = 1;
int resultado = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * NUMEROS);    // NUMEROS = 2
resultado[0] = a;
resultado[1] = b;
// ... Trabajamos con la variable resultado
free(resultado);
```

En este caso, hemos reservado espacio para dos elementos, y si quieres meter un tercero, deberás pedir más memoria al sistema operativo.

```
int a = 13;
int b = 1;
int resultado = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * NUMEROS);    // NUMEROS = 2
resultado[0] = a;
resultado[1] = b;
resultado = (int *) realloc(resultado, NUEVO_SIZE);    // NUEVO_SIZE = sizeof(int) * 3 (tiene que ser mayor que el tamaño original)
resultado[2] = 45;
// ...
free(resultado);
```

Otra opción es utilizar una lista de enteros para almacenarlos. Para ello deberías saber cómo implementar un TAD, qué tipos de listas hay, y también algo de manejo de memoria dinámica.

Más información sobre listas [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_enlazada).

También te dejo [aquí](https://www.monografias.com/trabajos90/listas-c/listas-c.shtml) un enlace sobre cómo implementar una lista simplemente enlazada en C.

Comment: grax bro, lo leere e intentare hacerlo de varias manera para aprender, muchas gracias! :3